# Parsing sections from a log file using F#

Tags: f#

After reading a lot about F#, I am today cutting my very first real life F# code and I'd appreciate any feedback on my approach.

I'm writing a simple utility to analyse a log file.  The code below represents my approach for identifying sections of the log and representing them in a structure.  The "real life" situation is to find application sessions in the log file.  The example below model this by parsing a list of numeric strings!

The main areas of relevance are the `GetSection` and `GetSections` methods below.  My questions are:

- Is my approach sensible?
- Is this functional and idiomatic?
- Is there an alternative approach that would be clearer or more elegant?

There is a LinqPad version of the code available here: http://share.linqpad.net/99khmx.linq

```
//  Here are the "lines" from my "log file".
let lines = [1 .. 25] |> List.map (fun x -> x.ToString())

// For this exercise, section criteria is divisibility by 5.
// val DivisibleByFive : s:string -> bool
let DivisibleByFive (s:string) = 
    System.Int32.Parse(s) % 5 = 0

// I am going to use the following type to hold the information
// from each section of the log.
type Section (lines:string list) =
    member x.Lines = lines

// Read a single section from the top of the log (based on: http://fssnip.net/iV).
// val GetSection : lines:string list -> Section * string list
let GetSection (lines:string list) = 
    let rec getSection (l:string list) result =
        match l with
        | h::t when DivisibleByFive h -> 
            let values = h::result |> List.rev
            (new Section(values), t)
        | h::t when not (DivisibleByFive h)  -> 
            getSection t (h::result)
        | _ -> 
            (new Section(result), [])
    getSection lines []    

// Get a list of all sections from the log.
// val GetSections : lines:string list -> Section list
let GetSections (lines:string list) = 
    let rec getSections (l:string list) result = 
        match GetSection l with
        | (a, []) -> (a::result)
        | (a, b) -> getSections b (a::result)
    getSections lines [] |> List.rev


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let sections = GetSections lines
    sprintf "Parsed %d section from the log:" sections.Length |> System.Console.WriteLine
    for i in sections do
        sprintf "  Section starting with %s" i.Lines.[0] |> System.Console.WriteLine
    let s = System.Console.ReadLine()
    0
```

---

**Edit**: The refactored code following the comments by @mjolka is below (including the bug fix mentioned in @mjolka's update).  The refactored code is available as a [LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/9mqxl7.linq) or a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/seankearon/20d6b0c1c0e10bbd13dd).

```
//  Here are the "lines" from my "log file".
let lines = [1 .. 25] |> List.map (fun x -> x.ToString())

// For this exercise, section criteria is divisibility by 5.
// val DivisibleByFive : s:string -> bool
let DivisibleByFive (s:string) = 
    System.Int32.Parse(s) % 5 = 0

// I am going to use the following type to hold the information
// from each section of the log.
type Section (lines:string list) =
    member x.Lines = lines

/// <summary>
/// Splits the given sequence into non-empty contiguous subsequences, such
/// that the last element of every subsequence (except possibly the last)
/// satisfies the given predicate. No other elements satisfy the predicate.
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// <c>
/// let even x = x % 2 = 0
/// printfn "%A" (splitAtEach even (seq { 1 .. 3 }))
/// printfn "%A" (splitAtEach even (seq { 1 .. 4 }))
/// </c>
/// The output is:
/// <c>
/// seq [[1; 2]; [3]]
/// seq [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]
/// </c>
/// </example>
let splitAtEach (predicate : 'T -> bool) (xs : seq<'T>) : seq<'T list> =
    let section = new ResizeArray<'T>()
    seq {
        for x in xs do
            section.Add x
            if predicate x then
                yield Seq.toList section
                section.Clear()
        if section.Any() then
            yield Seq.toList section
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let sections =
        splitAtEach DivisibleByFive lines
        |> Seq.map (fun lines -> new Section(lines))
        |> Seq.toList
    printfn "Parsed %d section from the log:" sections.Length
    sections |> List.iter (fun section -> printfn "  Section starting with %s" 
    let _ = System.Console.ReadLine() // or System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of F#! Your code is looking good, and thanks for posting the LinqPad file. Here are a couple of pointers:

- `sprintf ... |> System.Console.WriteLine` can be replaced by a call to `printfn`.
- The variable name `i` in the for loop is misleading, as it looks like an index. Calling it `section` would be better.
- If you don't need the result of an expression, such as `System.Console.ReadLine`, it's common to name the variable `_`.

Then your `main` function would look like this:

```
let main argv = 
    let sections = GetSections lines
    printfn "Parsed %d section from the log:" sections.Length
    for section in sections do
        printfn "  Section starting with %s" section.Lines.Head
    let _ = System.Console.ReadLine()
    0
```

You could also write the `for` loop using `List.iter`, but it's a matter of personal preference:

```
sections |> List.iter (fun section -> printfn "  Section starting with %s" section.Lines.Head)
```

Now to the main part of your code. I would say that it's functional and idiomatic, but in my experience with F#, sometimes it's best to compromise on the functional approach.

For example, consider `GetSections`. The basic idea is to go through a sequence, building up lists until a certain predicate is met. I feel that the functional approach, with its list reversal, obscures the intention of the code. Here is what I would propose:

**Edit** Fixed a bug where last elements might not be returned.

```
/// <summary>
/// Splits the given sequence into non-empty contiguous subsequences, such
/// that the last element of every subsequence (except possibly the last)
/// satisfies the given predicate. No other elements satisfy the predicate.
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// <c>
/// let even x = x % 2 = 0
/// printfn "%A" (splitAtEach even (seq { 1 .. 3 }))
/// printfn "%A" (splitAtEach even (seq { 1 .. 4 }))
/// </c>
/// The output is:
/// <c>
/// seq [[1; 2]; [3]]
/// seq [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]
/// </c>
/// </example>
let splitAtEach (predicate : 'T -> bool) (xs : seq<'T>) : seq<'T list> =
    let section = new ResizeArray<'T>()
    seq {
        for x in xs do
            section.Add x
            if predicate x then
                yield Seq.toList section
                section.Clear()
        if section.Any() then
            yield Seq.toList section
    }
```

Then `GetSections` could be written

```
let GetSections lines =
    splitAtEach DivisibleByFive lines
    |> Seq.map (fun lines -> new Section(lines))
    |> Seq.toList
```

**Edit** Found a bug in your definition of `GetSections`, where `GetSections ["1"; "2"; "3"] = [["3"; "2"; "1"]]`.

Comment: another common thing is doing something like `System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore` without ever using `let` (yeah it reads a bit strange)

Comment: @mjolka - thank you, that's really useful and has helped me a lot.  I agree that `GetSections` and `GetSection` were not expressing their intent as clearly as they should have been.  That's a valuable lesson! :)  Using Seq is much clearer and I can get a whole lot of reuse from `splitAtEach` in the "real" code. Very much appreciated! An updated LinqPad version is here: http://share.linqpad.net/as8ivp.linq.

Comment: I've also now updated the question to show the refactored code.

Comment: @SeanKearon I've fixed a bug in my code, please see the edit.

Comment: Thank you - I've updated the finished code above and in the LinqPad sample.